# ASP.net consuming WCF Soap/Rest Services

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest, soap

I have an ASP.net website which currently consumes a WCF service with a SOAP Protocol which is hosted to Azure Cloud Services.

I have then exposed that WCF Service as both Rest and Soap. (for other clients that wanted Json)

I have tried to configure the reference of the ASP.net site to support the existing soap endpoint of this WCF Service but I keep getting errors of missing object references, while my client calls work just fine.

I ve done some research but still I dont have a clear view on this.

Is this possible to maintain-stick to Soap Service Reference when a Rest coexists-or is it better to consume the Rest endpoint and modify my code according to Rest HTTP Requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beauty of WCF is to implement once and deploy (or host) in various protocol (as a different endpoint).

In your case if you have ASP.Net app which is currently consuming the WCF service with SOAP, its totally possible to expose the existing WCF service as a REST service without affecting the existing ASP.net App.

I have personally made one WCF service which was consumed by 3 App and all were consumed in a different protocol. Windowp app consumed it in tcp, while asp.net did in REST and a Php app did in SOAP. Refer to this [post](http://hectorcorrea.com/blog/multiple-endpoints-for-a-wcf-service) to get more clarity.

Share the specific inner exception of the issue you faced, so that I can help further.

Comment: Exception:
" 'myService.anObject' does not contain a definition for 'anotherObject', and no extension method 'anotherObject' accepting a first argument of type 'myService.anObject' could be found."

I configured the service reference to the URL of the new WCF(REST+SOAP) Service and the SOAP endpoint(i use Visual Studio 12). Just to clarify again client calls seem to be ok I just get the above exception several times. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry mate, seemed that I was missing really obvious. Works fine now. Thanks for your answer!